# "undocumented" constants in Ruby/Rdoc

Tags: ruby, rdoc

The following code snipped:

```
# ansi console color constants
COLOR_BLACK = 0
COLOR_RED = 1
COLOR_GREEN = 2
COLOR_YELLOW = 3
COLOR_BLUE = 4
COLOR_MAGENTA = 5
COLOR_CYAN = 6
COLOR_WHITE = 7

# functional color aliases
COLOR_WARN = COLOR_YELLOW
COLOR_ALERT = COLOR_RED
COLOR_CONFIRM = COLOR_GREEN
COLOR_NOTE = COLOR_BLUE
```

gets reported as 10 undocumented constants. Is there a way to "comment constants by groups" in RDoc? Documenting each constant separately would be slightly idiotic, and I don't want to omit them from doc.

Comment: is your problem the result of rdoc? or is html doc rendered wrongly?

Comment: it an "rdoc feature missing problem" ^^… i'd like to have the constants in the doc, but dont want to get them counted as undocumented and also dont want to dublicate them into commentary blocks; i'm looking for a pricipial solution, not a workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the following answer per mail from a rdoc-developer, after i suggested implementing a `:constlist:` directive, that would get `COLOR_BLACK = 0` simply documented as **COLOR_BLACK(0)**:

> I'll see what I can do, but I may not be able to add it to RDoc 4.0 as my time is limited.
>
> I think I can make this work by putting the constants in a section (internally) using a separate directive that also marks them as documented for the purposes of the coverage report.